# Logitech MX Keys Mini doesn’t pairing on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I recently purchased a logitech MX Keys Mini.
I tried connecting it via bluetooth to my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
The user interface shows me a passkey to enter and the keyboard starts working.
After a while the keyboard stops working and I have to enter a passkey again.

Trying to connect the keyboard via terminal, I noticed that it is not being paired with the bluetooth.
After typing the command pair MAC-ADDRESS, nothing happens.

How can I fix it?